# Generate a graph based on percentage in excel

Tags: charts

I have a table in excel with the below structure

Names  | Pass   | Fail    |

= ==== == ==== ==== == =====

NameA  |    2   |     3   |

---

NameB  |    6   |    7    |

---

NameC  |    3   |     4   |

---

The Pass/Fail details im getting from a series of rows using CountIF formula.
If i generate a graph now for this table in excel. I get the details based on the count. 
Eg: For Name A, out of 5 rows - 2 are pass and 3 are Fail

I wanted to acheive this graph interms of percentage as Y-axis in the graph which says out of 100% - 40% are pass adn 60% percent are fail.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot a percentage, calculate it in the sheet, and plot the calculations.

Alternatively, if you use a stacked 100% chart (column or bar), the bars will be scaled so they show the percentage. However, the data will still be the input values, and data labels will show these values and not percentages, and you will have both bars in the chart.